# Should addTrack or addStream be called only when the sdp exchange is complete?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have the following on my RTCPeerConnection instances:

```
        rtcConnection.sdpExchangeComplete = function () {
            const isComplete = this.signalingState == "stable" && this.localDescription != null && this.remoteDescription != null && this.remoteDescription.sdp.length > 0;
            return isComplete;
        };
```

I also use this to add a stream to the connection (via `adapter` - I know addTrack will be used in the future):

```
 connection.addStream(stream);
```

My question is - should we always wait for sdpExchangeComplete() to be `true` before calling `addStream`, or can the stream/tracks be added before the exchange is complete?

Comment: `sdpExchangeComplete` is not plain WebRTC. Please tag the question with the library you're using for better help. And to answer your question: no, tracks and streams are typically added ahead of creating the SDP, since they add information to the SDP. Add them later and you need to redo the exchange.

Comment: @jib it's mine.  thanks

Comment: I tend to add the stream to the channel even before creating the offer. If I need to add another stream to a connection, yes, I would wait for the connection to be established before I allow that. I am not sure what happens if I don't wait, but it might end up messing with the running candidate transfer process.